# Is there a way to disable a particular PCI port?

Tags: networking, hardware, pci

I have a MB with 2 NICs on it. A switch burned up and took out one of them. There is no way to turn them off individually in the BIOS. Is there a way to turn off one of the ports?  Can I unmap it, unbind it, power it down so the system doesn't see it at after boot?

They are mapped as `0000:02.08.0` and `0000:02.08.1`. I want to turn the second one off somehow. Since they both use the same driver, blacklisting the module will take out both of them. Normally I would just live with it but it seems there should be a way to do that, like in Windows I can just disable it. I Actually have the exact same problem on another computer running XCP so this will be a two-fer if it gets figured out.

The OS is 12.4 LTS server with Xen on it.

Answer (score 0):

do not think that it is possible to disable a particular pci port.
It is possible to disable a specific device with a custom udev rule:

You need to know the device mac. For example create a file
**/etc/udev/rules.d/90.disable.netcard.rules**

`SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="remove", DRIVERS=="?*", OPTIONS="ignore_device"
, ATTR{address}=="ZZ:AA:BB:CC:DD:EE", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"`

afterwards you have to restart udev